# What am I doing wrong here with echo list and bootstrap?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm echoing this list from my mysql database, but I don't want bullets so I'm using bootstrap list-group-item. I feel like I'm making a really dumb mistake somewhere with my list tags but I'm not sure. I'm still getting the bullets next to my list.  I'm not including all of my connecting to my database php because that's not the problem.

Here is what I have,

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
           <div class="panel-heading">Contents</div>
           <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">

                      <?php

                    basic connect to mysql database stuff here
                    }

                    $query = mysqli_query($dat, "SELECT * FROM Content ORDER BY ContentName") or die(mysqli_error($dat));
                        while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

                        echo"<li>";
                        echo"<a href = >";
                        echo $list['ContentName'];
                        echo"</a>";
                        echo "</li>";

                    }
                    mysqli_close($dat);
                    ?>

            </li>
           </ul>
         </div>
```

Comment: `echo"<a href = >";` ? Awful broken HTML. *but I don't want bullets so I'm using bootstrap list-group-item* doesn't make sense. Use a simple CSS `list-style: none` can make those bullets disappear already. And this question is not related to PHP at all. You can post the resultant HTML instead.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and an example output so we can see whats happening?

Comment: Raptor, it's just a dummy link for the assignment, and we are required to use list-group-item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are adding `li` inside another `li`. it should be -

```
<ul class="list-group">
                  <?php
                }

                $query = mysqli_query($dat, "SELECT * FROM Content ORDER BY ContentName") or die(mysqli_error($dat));
                    while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

                    echo"<li class='list-group-item'>";
                    echo"<a href = >";
                    echo $list['ContentName'];
                    echo"</a>";
                    echo "</li>";

                }
                mysqli_close($dat);
                ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah that was it, knew it was something simple! Thanks for the answer, sweet and to the point!

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo "<li class='list-group-item'>";` instead of **`<li>`**   and remove the `<li>` before php code.

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">Contents</div>
        <ul class="list-group">
           <?php

                  basic connect to mysql database stuff here
                  }

                  $query = mysqli_query($dat, "SELECT * FROM Content ORDER BY ContentName") or die(mysqli_error($dat));
                      while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

                      echo "<li class='list-group-item'>";
                      echo "<a href ='www.example.com' >";
                      echo $list['ContentName'];
                      echo "</a>";
                      echo "</li>";

                  }
                  mysqli_close($dat);
              ?>
         </ul>
    </div>
```